# System.net defaultProxy attributes are invalid

Tags: servicestack, app-config, fiddler

I am trying to capture my ServiceStack self-host calls in Fiddler.  I have added a system.net default proxy section to the app.config file as described on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  But VS won't accept the attributes

[image]

The error associated with the squiggles is "The attribute is invalid - The value is invalid according to its datatype 'NmToken' - The enumeration constraint failed.

Any idea how I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the easier solution for Fiddler of changing the BaseUrl on your client to use the name of your pc instead of localhost? e.g. `var client = JsonServiceClient("http://pcname:1337");`

Comment: That gives me a web service is unavailable error. With "http://*:1337/" I at least get the service acknowledged.